# .gitignore issue I need to only track files with !*02.* pattern but I am only able to exclude them not to track them with !*02.*

Tags: git, regex-negation

In a windows server, every day a folder is created with the date\several csv files.
I need to commit only the files that present the string *02.* in the name.

```
mm-dd-yy\filename02-fdsfsf.csv (ignore this pattern)
mm-dd-yy\data_collection_status (ignore this pattern)
mm-dd-yy\dat (ignore this pattern)
mm-dd-yy\filename02.mmddyy.csv (i want to commit only these types of file)
```

I created a .gitignore file as follows:

```
*
!.gitignore
!*02.*
```

And when I run git status it only identifies .gitignore .
To test changed the .gitignore file as follows:

```
*02.*
!.gitignore
```

As a result it ignored the files with the *02.* pattern.
This indicates the *02.* pattern is correct, so why it does not deny it when I use !*02.*  ?

Any help will be very welcome,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more testing and it seems that this pattern in the gitignore file solves the issue:

```
*
!**/
!*02.*
!.gitignore
```

Thanks anyway and how this is helpful

According with @torek, it will also works if we alter the second line from `!**/` to `!*/`

Please check the comments, you can find a very clear explanation, by @torek, on how it works.

Comment: The crucial part here is the second line (which must come *after* the first line). The line can be reduced to the simpler `!*/`, but the two-star version produces the same result.

Comment: nice, thanks @torek , indeed it also works ```!*/```, it took me a long time to figure it out (regarding the second line), I am still not sure if I understand the hierarchy to follow in order to obtain the expected results, but I did learn a lot today and thanks for your comment :)

Comment: The tricks here are: (1) Git obeys the lines "in order", as it were. (2) When Git finds a work-tree sub-directory (a folder within the main work-tree folder, or any sub-folder thereof) by scanning through the parent directory slowly, painfully, one entry at a time, it has a choice: scan the sub-directory itself slowly, painfully, one entry at a time? Or, skip the directory entirely, which will be much faster? Git will do the "skip entirely" if the `.gitignore` file allows it. The `!*/` entry tells it: *not allowed to skip any directory*.

Comment: Hence the variant with just `*` and `!*02.*` causes Git to *skip* all the sub-directories entirely. Adding `!*/` after `*` says "skip all files, *except* don't ever skip directories" and because the "except" is *later* it overrides. (Then the `!*02` and `!.gitignore` override for those files, too.)

Comment: I got your point, now it makes a lot more sense for me. Thanks for this kind explanation :)